# Proper regex for examination rating field

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I have a problem with regards to writing the correct regex for the examination rating field of my grails application. Users should have the option to either enter an alphabet character OR a number. Quantitative rating should range from 0-100, accepts decimal numbers with or without percentage sign (%) but exclude negative numbers. The regex should permit special characters percentage(%) and period (.) ONLY. Below is a set of possible input:

```
1) 100% (should pass the validation)
2) 100.0 (should pass the validation)
3) PASSED (should pass the validation)
4) FAILED (should pass the validation)
5) 100.1 (should not pass the validation)
6) -90 (should not pass the validation)
```

Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How come 100.1 is valid, while 100.0 is invalid?

Comment: And may I ask what does the input looks like when you pass it to the regex? Is it like `100%` or `1) 100%`?

Comment: Sorry for the typo error..the user has the option either to add a % symbol, so 100 or 100% is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the language is **Java**. I also assume that you want to validate user input, which ***expects*** to contain **only** the percentage.

```
"^\\s*((100(\\.0*)?|\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)%?|PASSED|FAILED)\\s*$"
```

(In Groovy, you don't have to escape the backslash)

```
/^\s*((100(\.0*)?|\d{1,2}(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)%?|PASSED|FAILED)\s*$/ (for Groovy)
```

The regex above will **only** validate numbers between 0.0 to 100.0. It allows arbitrary long number of digits after decimal points, and also allows cases such as `.8` or `45.` to pass, since they can be processed. The regex also allows any amount of spaces before and after the input (but not inside).

**EDIT**

To match plain text (ASCII):

```
"^\\s*((100(\\.0*)?|\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)%?|[a-zA-Z.]+)\\s*$"

/^\s*((100(\.0*)?|\d{1,2}(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)%?|[a-zA-Z.]+)\s*$/ (for Groovy)
```

This will match text that uses English alphabet character (case-insensitive), and full-period. E.g. `sdhSDFHS.sfSDJF.sdfSDJFI` will matches the above regex. Note that the current regex does not allow spaces within the text, but if you want to add more characters, add inside the square bracket (character class): `[a-zA-Z.]`. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.

**Testing code** (for Java)

```
String arr[] = {"100%", "  .435%", "3%", "0%", "0", ".0", "hdfjs.", "  PASSED", "FAILED", "34.5  ", "sdhf.sdfdsf.fsdf  ", " 100.0000 ", "-234.4", "-0.1", "34.", "100.0000001", "1000"};
for (String s: arr) 
    System.out.println(s + " " + (s.matches("^\\s*((100(\\.0*)?|\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)%?|[a-zA-Z.]+)\\s*$") ? "matched" : "not matched"));
```

**Output**

```
100% matched
  .435% matched
3% matched
0% matched
0 matched
.0 matched
hdfjs. matched
  PASSED matched
FAILED matched
34.5   matched
sdhf.sdfdsf.fsdf   matched
 100.0000  matched
-234.4 not matched
-0.1 not matched
34. matched
100.0000001 not matched
1000 not matched
```

**EDIT2**

Change in requirement as mentioned in the discussion: only match from 1.0 to 100.0 inclusive for the percentage:

```
/^\s*((100(\.0*)?|[1-9]\d?(\.\d*)?)%?|[a-zA-Z.]+)\s*$/ (for Groovy)
```

This condition is even more stricter than before, since `01.1` will not match. If you want to match this case:

```
/^\s*(0*((100(\.0*)?|[1-9]\d?(\.\d*)?)%?)|[a-zA-Z.]+)\s*$/ (for Groovy)
```

Comment: I am using groovy language which is based in Java. What I wanted to do here is to give the user an option to either input any string, but not limited to PASSED or FAIL only OR a number which range from 0-100 which may contain % sign, or decimal number.

Comment: @chemilleX3: How do you define "any string"? Since "any string" can be an invalid percentage input.

Comment: I am referring to alphabet characters, and special characters percentage(%) and period(.) only. thank you so much!

Comment: Im so sorry. but your code isn't working at all after I have implemented it on my code.

Comment: it doesn't accept any of the above combination. This is my original code: matches: /^[0-9a-zA-Z,.]*?[0-9a-zA-Z]+?[0-9a-zA-Z,%.-]*$/. This works fine, its just that, it cant filter input that is above 100. Do you have any idea to do enhance my regex?thanks much!

Comment: maybe your code is not working fine with me, since you've mentioned that you are using a Java language. In my case, im not using pure Java, im using groovy.

Comment: @chemilleX3: Would you please give me more example of what you want to be matched (the more the better)?

Comment: @chemilleX3: I have edited the post for Groovy. Apparently, Groovy is backed by Java regex, so both are interchangeable. The extra backslash is to escape the backslash in Java String, which is not necessary in Groovy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12587/discussion-between-chemillex3-and-nhahtdh)

Answer (score 1):

100.1 doesn't make sense. For the rest you can use [this](http://regexr.com?318tv) however:

```
^\d+\)\s*(PASSED|FAILED|0*(100(\.0+)?|[0-9]{1,2}(\.\d+)?)%?)$
```